# Access is denied on F:

Tags: windows, hard-drive, permissions

I don't know how I did this, but I don't have acces to the F: drive anymore. When I plug in my USB stick it appears under File Explorer as "Removable Device " and when I click on it I have a display message that says "F:\ is not accessible. Acces is denied ".

I tried to reset my registry since I have been a lot with GPOs lately and register values but I get an error message saying "Not all data was successfully written to the registry. Some keys are open by the system or other processes, or you have insufficient privileges to perform operation" whereas I logged as local administrator.

When I try to edit the F: drive permissions, I get an error saying that I don't have rights to do these actions.

I tried to create another administrator account, to disable UAC, to boot on safe mode and to change F: drive permissions but I still got the same rights error.

I tried to recover my PC but I get the "could not find the recovery environment " which is weird because I used this recovery option weeks ago and it worked without me putting and recovery media on the machine.

I am working on a windows 10 machine that doesn't have access on the internet.

Any ideas on what else I could try ?

Comment: It happened to me and I fixed it by editing two registry. I went to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices]` and `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices]`. Here you will see a key as `GUID`. At my system it is `{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}`. Here you will see two `dword` values. `Deny_Read` and `Deny_Write`. After setting value of these two to `0 ` and inserting my device again; it worked for me. You may give it a try.

Comment: I tried that but weirdly when run gpupdate /force the Deny_Write and Deny_Read values are back to 0x00000030

Comment: That's correct. It will reset every time group policy is implemented. However, you should be able to access your device after updating these values and reinserting USB stick.

Comment: I had to edit more registers than the two you mentionned but it worked I can access my F: drive thank you ! How can I fix the situation permanently though ?

Comment: You seems to be contradicting your actions. You are implementing GPO to prevent access to mass storage device on one hand; and on the other had, you want to access mass storage device without any restriction. To fix it permanently, remove GPO restriction for mass storage device. I have not yet tried, but once device is installed properly and you are able to access it; you should be able to access it in future as well. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Ok so I don't really understand why but to be able to access my drive I have to disable the GPO restriction for mass storage device and not just choose the "Not configured" state like I did... Thanks a lot for your help  @Sandeep